# Storing and serving an infinite news feed

Tags: database, data-structures, feed

For the sake of this question and to illustrate my problem better, let's try and debug how instagram would possibly serve its **infinitely scrollable feed**. (Also, note that this question is about how they serve the feed, and **not** about how they rank the posts in the feed.)

Here's what I have got:

1. The user opens the app at **t1**. It sends a request to fetch the feed for this user.
2. The server finds all the posts between **t1** (current time) and **t0** (user's last activity time). Let's say these turn out to be **1000**.
3. The server then **filters posts out** of these **1000** that would be relevant to this particular user. Let's say it ends up with **250** posts.
4. The server then uses a **blackbox to rank (score) these posts** based on some huerisitcs.
5. After this, it stores this **250 IDs of the posts in REDIS**.
6. Out of the 250 IDs, it paginates and finds out **first 30 ids**. It then queries all the information for these 30 posts and sends the result back to the caller.

All cool? Good.

Now, the user scrolls down and soon she has exhausted 15 posts. Since Instagram is cool, it notices that the user has already exhausted 15 and automatically fetches the **next 30 posts** without the user seeing the "LOADING" progress bar.

Somwhere down the road, here's what happens at the server: It **runs out of the cached 250 IDs** stored in REDIS.

***TIME KEY:***

**t0:** User's last activity before opening the app today. (Could be **two days before**, could be **5 hours**. We don't know.)

**t1:** User opened the app today for the first time.

**t2:** User scrolled past the first 30 posts and asked for more posts. Or User liked a post. Could be any kind of activity. We don't know.

If it receives a request now, it has to show old content. Older than `t0`. This is because as you scroll down, you are actually going in the past. Since, the user's last activity was **t0** (when he last time opened the app, not right now), we then have to find posts that are older than **t0**. However, we no longer store **t0** as user's last activity has maybe changed to **t6**.

How do I solve this?

Also, if the user scrolls back up, and asks for new posts: We still need to calculate new posts after **t1** (that's when the user opened the app right now) till right now and add them to the REDIS cache **AT THE TOP.**

How do I keep track of these **t0, t1,** etc.? What is the fastest way of doing this?